# Values on Multiple custom fields in Solspace Super Search

Tags: solspace, supersearch

According to the documentation here: https://solspace.com/docs/super_search/search_syntax/#custom_fields

I should be able to pass values from multiple custom fields into my search query. For example, I want to pass the following:

```
doctors_services-exact=Surgery&doctors_locations-exact=My%20Medical%Center
```

These custom fields are relationship fields, where I'm trying to filter on the exact title of each relationship. So, I have a service named "Surgery" and a location named "My Medical Center". Trying each one of these individually works - I get the expected results.

Both of these queries work:

```
doctors_services-exact=Surgery
```

OR

```
doctors_locations-exact=My%20Medical%Center
```

But in combination, it does not work. Any help on this would be great!

**UPDATE:**

I'm using SuperSearch 2.2.3 and EE 2.10.1. I'm trying to pass two values in the search string - these are the only two search criteria I'm passing - there are no keywords or any other parameters.

This search string is intended to find all doctors with a relationship to a "Generic Hospital Name". It works correctly - the search results show only doctors with a relationship to "Generic Hospital Name":

```
search&channel=doctors&doctors_locations-exact=Generic%Hospital%Name
```

This search string is intended to find all doctors with a relationship to "Primary Care". It works correctly - the search results show only doctors with a relationship to "Primary Care":

```
search&channel=doctors&doctors_services-exact=Primary%20Care
```

I need to combine these in the event that someone needs to find a doctor specializing in "Primary Care" at "Generic Hospital Name". So, this is my search string for that:

```
search&channel=doctors&doctors_services-exact=Primary%20Care&doctors_locations-exact=Generic%20Hospital%20Name
```

This does not work. I get ALL doctors who work at "Generic Hospital Name", however, they are NOT ALL "Primary Care" doctors.

If I remove exact on doctors_services like this:

```
search&channel=doctors&doctors_services=Primary%20Care&doctors_locations-exact=Generic%20Hospital%20Name
```

The results for this returns a mixed bag of doctors. The -exact on doctors_locations doesn't limit the doctors from "Generic Hospital Name" nor does it return accurate results for doctors_services. I'd expect to see doctors with services that include the words "Primary" or "Care", but the first doctor in the list specializes in "Lung Transplants" and "Abdominal Surgery".

If I remove -exact from doctors_locations like this:

```
search&channel=doctors&doctors_services-exact=Primary%20Care&doctors_locations=Generic%20Hospital%20Name
```

I also get a mixed bag of the results that does not seem to obey either doctors_services or doctors_locations.

Removing exact from both doctors_services and doctors_locations does not produce a comprehensible list of search results either.

So I can pass -exact on doctors_locations OR doctors_services just as long as they do not exist in the same query. doctors_locations-exact works by itself, doctors_services-exact works by itself, but not together.

Comment: What version of Super Search are you using? (please provide a version number) Are those two search criteria the only criteria in your search? Is there a difference if the search is _not_ an `-exact` search? When you mention that it doesn't work, do you mean you get _no results_, or that you get results from doctor_services OR doctors_locations instead of doctor_services AND doctors_locations? If the latter, "OR" searching is the current known behavior for searching 2 relationship fields?

Comment: If "OR" searching is the current known behavior for searching 2 relationship fields, is there a way to make it "AND" searching? I need the same functionality we have with categories where I can pass a double ampersand "&&"

Comment: I'd second the question if there is a way to make custom fields be "and" instead of "or" so adding additional custom fields narrows down/filters the results.